# C# assembly load of ASP.NET Core framework assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a tool that goes through and does some inspections on my project - so it loops through all the assemblies, loads them and does some stuff. All the assemblies I have load fine except one. An assembly that has this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

at the top. When I try to do an `Assembly.LoadFile` of that assembly - I get an `AssemblyResolve` event for this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll
```

I did googling and found a suggestion I add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` - so I did, and got

> The Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package is not supported when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher. A framework reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App should be used instead, and will be implicitly included by Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

The weird thing is - I looked in my solution, I looked in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net` and I looked in `C:\program files\Microsoft\visual studio` - and I can't find that dll appearing anywhere. And it's not just trying to assembly resolve it - not being able to find that dll  causes the assembly load to fail - I don't actually get a loaded assembly.

At a loss as to how to fix this - if I could find the dlls somewhere - I could manually load them on the assembly resolve event.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please try [reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/razor-pages/web-sdk) next time. `Implicitly references: The ASP.NET Core shared framework.`

Comment: so please help - how does that help me know where to load the dlls from?   honest question, not snarky answer.   I still do not know.

Comment: You aren't supposed to load the DLLs yourself, the .NET project or build system will do it for you. My guess is that your inspection tool doesn't use standard analysis mechanisms like Roslyn code analysis, and thus can't benefit from these built-ins. Which would make this an X-Y problem, with the correct answer being "rewrite your tool to use Roslyn analysis".